# Hung Threads java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jakarta-ee, classloader

My J2EE application is performing slow. We took the Thead Dumps during that situation and found that following thread was Runnable in multiple dumps and has taken locks on some monitors which cause other threads (directly or indirectly) waiting for the locks.

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(ClassLoader.java:891) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:301) 
    - locked [0x9747c360] (a sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:299) 
    - locked [0x9747c318] (a sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) 
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268) 
    - locked [0x9747c318] (a sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251) 
.....
```

Can you please suggest which this thread is not moving and letting other threads work?

Comment: it'd help if you tell the version of java and the application server you use. The other threads are waiting for the classloader locks which is normal, however how that particular thread blocks in the native method would make me think you might have either hardware/disk issues or corrupted jar files.  You can start the application server in debug and pause the process to see which class is the culprit.

Comment: @bestsss Java: 1.5. AppServer: WAS 7.0

Comment: When does the slow down occur? Just after startup or after the system has been running for a while or randomly? Not intimate with WAS myself but I'd check that all debug-related parameters are off and that nothing's modifying your app once deployed. It looks like websphere could be reloading your application multiple times.

Comment: Can you display more of the thread dump?

Comment: which exactly java 1.5, the reason i ask: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4942470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are your app loading so many classes (the locks are in the loadClass)? It is expected that your app load unloaded classes just during initialization and warm up.

So, I suspect that one of the following things are happening:

- You are creating a lot of different dynamic proxy classes instead of trying to reuse them.
- You are creating a lot of ClassLoaders unnecessarily, or at least misusing them.
- You are starting and terminating multiple parallel JVMs.

Needless to say, any of these things are very expensive and should be avoided the maximum possible.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But we are not using either of the 3 above mentioned things. Our application is a straight J2EE application that does not use customized class loaders and exploits the default class loading mechanism.
Also, agree that the application will load many classes during initialization, but the behavior in question is too long after the startup in the real production environment.
We suspected this could be issue because of memory space in Perm-Gen issue but this is also ruled out after increasing the perm-gen space and monitoring the same which seems fine.

Comment: Java VM will dynamically load classes the first time they are used; while most classes may be loaded during warm-up, any request that causes the app to take a previously untaken path may load additional classes. The full thread dump would point out what triggered the class load.

Answer (score 1):

If this thread is paused *indefinitely* I'd guess its a circular reference of some sort (symlinks? other?).

If you enable logging for classes loaded you may be able to find out more.

```
java -verbose:class your.Class
```

This might show you a lot; I believe it writes to system.out so you'll have to check in the appropriate log.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this sort of thing happen in OSGI, where the classloader structure is a graph rather than a tree as is usual J2EE. Classloaders lock themselves when loading a class, so two threads (a, b) loading classes from classloaders in order of (x, y) and (y, x) respectively may deadlock. This could happen if static initializers cause more classloading from the other classloader. It's not frequent that the bootstrap classes cause classloading from the app class loader, but any factory classes in standard libraries that use the thread context loader would fit the bill. The usual solution is to get the classes loaded at an earlier time, during app startup perhaps, thus breaking the cycle.